# How do I stop Emacs automatically inserting hyphens at the beginning of new lines in fundamental fill mode

Tags: emacs, fill

I'm jotting down some notes in Emacs in Fundamental Fill mode.  I'm starting each one of my notes with a "-" on a new line.  The problem is, whenever one of the notes I'm writing is too long to fit on a single line, it gets pushed down to the next line (which I want to happen) but Emacs goes ahead and automatically inserts another "-" for me out the front on the new line (which I don't want to happen).  Is there a way to stop Emacs from exhibiting this "helpful" behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For note taking with emacs you could try emacs-org and M-x remember (both work with one another).

Another slightly offtopic answer would be to use word-wrap: you could let long line be longline in the file, but let emacs wrap line at word boundary for better readability with `M-x toggle-word-wrap`

Finaly, you can set adaptive-fill-mode to nil in your .emacs to remove this adaptive filling:

```
(setq adaptive-fill-mode ())
```

You could also look at `adaptive-fill-regexp` (see Emacs documentation for it)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using the `filladapt` package, which is much more sophisticated about how and where it inserts things.   I added the following lines to my .emacs file:

```
(require 'filladapt)
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'turn-on-filladapt-mode)
```